# How can I refactor this line of code:

Tags: python, if-statement, refactoring

I'm writing a program to check if sudoku is solved. Here is a part which I can't think of a way to refactor:

```
for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 9):
        if i < 3:
            if j < 3:
                one.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if j >= 3 and j < 6:
                two.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if j >= 6:
                three.append(sudoku[i][j])
        if i >= 3 and i < 6:
            if j < 3:
                four.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if j >= 3 and j < 6:
                five.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if j >= 6:
                six.append(sudoku[i][j])
        if i >= 6:
            if j < 3:
                seven.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if i >= 6 and j >= 3 and j < 6:
                eight.append(sudoku[i][j])
            if j >= 6:
                nine.append(sudoku[i][j])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a 2D array to hold your objects and map them as follows:

```
mapping = [[one, two, three], [four, five, six], [seven, eight, nine]]

for i in range(0, 9):
    for j in range(0, 9):
        square = mapping[i/3][j/3]
        square.append(sudoku[i][j])
```

If you are using Python 3, you would replace `square = mapping[i/3][j/3]` with `square = mapping[int(i/3)][int(j/3)]` or `square = mapping[i//3][j//3]` as Padraic pointed out

The reason for this is that Python2 will round down and return an `int` for division, where as Python3 will return a `float`. Casting to an `int` will round down.

Comment: why not `i//3` for python3?

Comment: well first time for everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your blocks `one`, `two`, etc... in an array. Then pick the right block in the array, depending on `i` and `j`. Basically, you want this index:

```
index = (i / 3) * 3 + j / 3
```

Where you are doing integer division.